# Error: AVD cannot be created in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

I'm trying to create an AVD for my QT Creator, I keep getting this error and now I don't know what to do.
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

[image: Screenshot of error here...]

Comment: Please put error messages in textual form into your question, external links will disappear eventually and make your question unreadable. And many viewers will not follow external links anyhow for security reasons.

Comment: @Jens that's the standard imgur subdomain used for embedded images on StackOverflow.

Comment: @musicamente It didn't show up on my Windows computer so I didn't touch it. Today on Safari it is actually showing up. Which shows that embedded images are a bad idea when text will do the job better anyhow.